# Concorrência WebServices ASMX com Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net, asmx

Percebi que quando chamados por XHR, os webservices ASMX conseguem lidar com poucas requisições simultâneas. Considere o seguinte cenário:

Página ASPX:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="scrManager" runat="server">
     <Services>
         <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService.asmx" />
     </Services>
 </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Método do WebService:

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   return "Hello World";
}
```

E o código Javascript que o chama:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ws = new WebApplication1.WebService();

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        function sucesso() {
            var end = new Date().getTime();
            var time = end - start;
            console.log('Duração: ' + time);
        }

        ws.HelloWorld(sucesso, function () { alert("erro"); });
    }
});
```

E o resultado, é mais ou menos esse:

[image]

Eu esperava que cada requisição demorasse aproximadamente 1s, porém a cada mais ou menos 5 requisições, o tempo de espera aumenta. Ou seja, a requisição ficou em espera, pois havia outras conexões abertas. A minha pergunta é: como aumentar a quantidade de requisições simultâneas, de forma que mais chamadas demorem o mesmo tempo. Sei que não seria bom que as 100 requisições fossem abertas de uma vez, mas acho muito pouco o número que tenho atualmente.

Pesquisando por aí, encontrei a seguinte configuração (web.config) mas não deu certo:

```
<system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
    <add address="*" maxconnection="40"/>
  </connectionManagement>
 </system.net>
```

<sub>**Nota:** Sei que os web services feitos com asmx são uma tecnologia legada, mas tenho um sistema grande inteiro que os usa no front end, de maneira semelhante a exposta aqui.  Não é uma opção agora mudar a tecnologia.</sub>

Comment: Boa pergunta, não entendo porque Asp.net aqui é pouco visitado.

Comment: Uma vez que alteraste o limite máximo de pedidos do lado do servidor e não produziu os resultados esperados, será possível que o "bottleneck" esteja do lado do cliente? Poderá existir no cliente um limite de pedidos?

Comment: Não acho que seja do lado do cliente, pelo que me lembro se fizer a chamada do webservice via c# o resultado era o mesmo. Acho que a config que expus aqui que não é a correta, preciso descobrir qual é, se existir. Vou fazer os testes de chamada via .NET e postar o resultado aqui para tirar a teima de um possível gargalo no cliente.

Comment: Tente implementar seu método e suas chamadas de forma assíncrona, isto deve melhorar seus resultados.

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 2):

Uma possível forma de abordar o problema é declarar o `[WebMethod]` em duas partes - uma de tipo `IAsyncResult` que inicia a chamada e uma de tipo `string` que a finaliza. Eu estou sem acesso à um servidor IIS para testar, mas eu me baseei nesse post: http://chroniclesofnojo.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/asynchronous-asmx-web-services.html

Além disso, se você está usando ASP 2.0 integrado ao IIS7, você precisa setar a configuração de `MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU` para lidar com o threading. Fonte: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis

Comment: Não resolve para mim essa solução por dois motivos: uma pois essa abordagem só funciona quando o serviço é referenciado via Web Reference no Visual Studio. Então o serializador se vira para chamar esses dois métodos como se fossem um. Eu estou chamando o WebService via Javascript, então não tenho como lidar com isso. Em sgundo lugar, sou obrigado a retornar no primeiro método um `IAsyncResult`, e nem sempre isso será possível no meu cenário. Quanto ao `MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU`, estou usando o .NET 4.5 e ele já resolve isso para mim.

Comment: Como vc chama não é importante; a implementação do `IAsyncResult` está no servidor, não no client.

Comment: Faz diferença sim. Não tem como fazer essa chamada usando `IAsyncResult ` usando Javascipt, pois um método acaba virando dois. Ela é específica para quando se faz a referência via `Add Web Reference` no Visual Studio.